# Django database error: sqlite3.OperationalError: near "SCHEMA": syntax error

Tags: django, django-models, sqlite

I'm integrating a Django app with circleci which is being deployed at heroku. However, after setting up Heroku and installing 'django_heroku' circleci tests keep failing due to some configuration error with the database. I currently do not have a database and just want the tests to run. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You haven't provided any information which would make it possible to answer this question. Nevertheless, you can't use sqlite on Heroku.

Comment: I think that was the problem, I changed to Postgres and the problem disappeared.